# ddebs missing for hardy?

Tags: package-management, 8.04, debug, debugging

I'm trying to debug some crashes on a 8.04 LTS server, but the ddebs repository at http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/ no longer has a directory for hardy...

Any ideas where the debug symbols for hardy have moved to?

Comment: what is that archive?

Comment: @enzotib: Debug debs packages @James: I think you are out of luck... those are gone and I did not find someone else hosting them. Unsuported system so the only answer you are going to get is... install the latest lts:10.04  :X

Comment: Hardy is technically still supported (on the Desktop for about three days, but still for another two years on the server, as this question is about)

Comment: @Rinzwind - hardy is still supported until 2013 for server installations.

Answer (score 1):

I would open a bug report. Ubuntu 8.04 Server is still supported till April 2013 and being able to debug crashes is crucial after all.

Anyway, if you urgently need packages with debugging information, you can rebuild them like described in this question: [How do I rebuild a package to include debugging information?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41610/how-do-i-rebuild-a-package-to-include-debugging-information)

Comment: Sure. But which package should I open a bug against?

Comment: Probably against Ubuntu the project: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu It's maybe also worth trying to write a mail to the ubuntu-server mailing list: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-server