# How do I rebuild a package to include debugging information?

Tags: package-management, debugging

I want to rebuild a package to include debugging symbols, how would I do that? There is no `-dbg` package available and also no `-dbgsym` package from the *ddebs* repository.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this in just a few steps:

1. Get the necessary tools and build dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install devscripts fakeroot
   sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
   ```
2. Set the build options:

   ```
   export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="debug nostrip noopt"
   ```
3. Build the package:

   ```
   fakeroot apt-get source -b <package>
   ```
4. Install the package:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i <package>*.deb
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively install the `pkg-create-dbgsym` package.