# How to install Mono from source?

Tags: compiling, mono

I am trying to install Mono from source (because in the future I will need to fix a bug in it).

PROBLEM: The compiled Mono does not behave properly.

Note:  http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Git is not the whole answer. [SparkleShare](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare) runs fine on Ubuntu's packaged Mono, but I get a `TypeLoadException` after following the instructions on that page, so some [DLL settings](http://www.mono-project.com/Config_DllMap) or something need to be configured too (confirmed on IRC), but I can't find a complete documentation, that is why I ask here.

---

I also tried this:

1. Install Ubuntu 2012.04 (Mono is not installed by default)
2. `sudo apt-get install curl git`
3. Compile+Install Mono 2.11 using [this automatic script](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/08/install-mono-2-10-3-on-ubuntu-using-bash-script/)

I am testing with SparkleShare.
Installing the .deb package would retrieve Ubuntu's Mono package (which I don't want).
[Building SparkleShare](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/blob/master/SparkleShare/Linux/README.md) on the machine itself fails saying `Package requirements (mono >= 2.8) were not met).

So I just ran`sudo make install` after having compiled on a machine.

When I run it (`mono bin/SparkleShare.exe`):

```
A type load exception has occurred. at SparkleShare.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]
```

The exact same thing works fine if I use Ubuntu's Mono instead of the built-from-source Mono.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding the source package, using the instructions given in the question [How do I rebuild a package to include debugging information?](https://askubuntu.com/a/41611/4066)

As a bonus, I get debugging information :-)

Then I can modify the Mono source that has been downloaded in step 3, and re-run from step 3 to have my modified Mono.